# ORMLite foreign collection order

Tags: java, ormlite

I have ORMLite db object and it has a field:

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
public ForeignCollection<BlockMod> blocks;
```

Now when I want to get all collection of blocks for current object I call:

```
public BlockMod[] getBlocks(){
   return blocks.toArray((BlockMod[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(BlockMod.class, blocks.size()));
}
```

My question is how to get this collection with custom sorting?
I know I could iterate this data and order it as I want, but is that the best solution?

Is ORMLite doing db request when I ask for ForeignCollection, or is it collected when I initialized main Object?

Comment: But does ForeignCollection class support ordering items? Maybe it will be easier sort when creating array.. Edit: i checked EagerForeignCollection  class and it uses List internally so probably yes

Comment: I really don't know much about it. I presume it is making separate request to get ForeignCollection, if so I should be able to modify it. I always need it sorted by one specific field. There has to be more elegant solution then just sorting array.

Comment: well, HQL support Clause 'Order by' so i guess ORMLite could too. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes it does, and I do use it to get data out. But I have no idea how to do it with ForeignCollection. Normally I would do it like this:
_list = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getHelper().getStoryDAO().queryBuilder().orderBy(StoryModKeys.CREATED_AT,false).where().eq(StoryModKeys.DELETED,false).query();

Comment: well you just need read Docs: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/ForeignCollectionField.html#orderColumnName%28%29

Comment: Nice. This is almost what I need. Now I will be able to get data sorted by some field.
But it doesn't completely answer my question, what if I want to sort it by multiple fields ?

Comment: the create view in database.

Answer (score 2):

may be, this code
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, orderColumnName = "name")
help you to custom sorting for Foreign Collection